# Count number of words in one list that appear in a string

Tags: regex, r, string, grepl

I have a unique set of words in a character vector (that have been 'stemmed') and I want to know how many of them appear in a string.

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(RTextTools)

string <- "Players Information donation link controller support years fame glory addition champion Steer leader gang ghosts life Power Pellets tables gobble ghost"
wordstofind <- c("player","fame","field","donat")

# I created a stemmed list of the string
string.stem <- colnames(create_matrix(string, stemWords = T, removeStopwords = F))
```

I know the next step probably involves `grepl("\\bword\\b,value")` or some usage of regex, but I'm not sure what the fastest option is in this case.

Here are my criteria:

- I have to do this many times, so it being as fast as possible is a concern.
- It should match the entire word ("es" shouldn't match "test").

Any push in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I never work with huge datasets, so time is never of the essence, but given the data you've provided this will give you a count of how many words *exactly* match something in the string.  Might be a good starting point.

```
sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(strsplit(string, " ")))

> sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(strsplit(string, " ")))
[1] 1
```

**Edit** Using the stems to get the proper 3 matches, thanks to @Anthony Bissel:

```
sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(string.stem))

> sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(string.stem))
[1] 3
```

Comment: The result should actually be 3, so that doesn't work, but it might just be that you used `string` rather than the stemmed vector.

Comment: How do you get 3? In the example provided, the only exact and whole-word match is fame.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the explanation where I stemmed the string to compare.  `sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(string.stem))` This works, and it looks like your solution is faster than mine. See my answer below.

Comment: Ah, I guess I missed the the part about getting the stems. Oops. Well I'm happy it still works. Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [stringr](https://github.com/hadley/stringr) by Hadley Wickham. You are probably looking for the function `str_count`.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly might be a faster option, but this works:

```
length(wordstofind) - length(setdiff(wordstofind, string.stem)) # 3
```

But it looks like Andrew Taylor's answer is faster:

```
`microbenchmark(sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(string.stem)), length(wordstofind) - length(setdiff(wordstofind, string.stem)))
Unit: microseconds
                                                        expr    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval
                   sum(wordstofind %in% unlist(string.stem))  4.016  4.909  6.55562  5.355  5.801 37.485   100
length(wordstofind) - length(setdiff(wordstofind, string.stem)) 16.511 16.958 21.85303 17.404 18.296 81.218   100`
```